# I need help finding the first derivative of this function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I've got the following equation and I'm trying to find the first derivative with respect to t

$A_t = C_t\int_0^\omega[P_t(x)\cdot G_t(x)] dx$

Context: This isn't a textbook question. I am an engineer working with a range of devices (literally 1000s) that produce things at variable rates depending on the device age. We're doing some theoretical research.

- A is the amount of product at time t
- x is the age of the device
- C is just some constant at time t
- $\omega$ is the maximum life of a single device
- P(x) is basically the population distribution. It's like a human
  population pyramid. Most devices are young but we do get some
  older ones from separate manufacturers or repairs
- G(x) is the 'productivity function'. Our devices actually take some time to become
  fully productive (coding, sorting out defects etc). And then their
  productivity trails off after they reach peak productivity (wear &
  tear). So this function is sort of like  a normal distribution. Sort of.
- $\int_0^\omega$ therefore essentially just sums up what all the devices are producing across their respective ages (population * production)

Anyway, I'm trying to find an expression for rate of change with respect to time. Haven't done math in decades so I'm rather lost. My formula may even be misspecified. I'm thinking should everything be multiplied by t to express production over time t instead of as at time t? Anyway, I appreciate the support.

Thank you.